# How to show maximum divs per row with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a dialog that will display the orders of my site, along with the contents of each. Each order has its own box. I'm having problems getting the divs formatted to show the maximum number of boxes in a row.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thuzm1ny/2/) shows the problem. As you can see, the boxes are squeezed into one row and the rows in each box break to a new line, which I don't want.

I have the widths set in the css and dialog code but what I really want is a dialog that opens to the full width, or maybe 90%, of the main page.

Would someone please point out my mistakes?

```
    <style>
    .test-container {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-reorder-direction: row-reverse;
        reorder-direction: row-reverse;
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    .test-item {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        width: 33%; 
        margin: 10px;    
    }
    </style>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div").dialog({
          modal: true,
          title: "My Dialog",
          minHeight: 100,
          minWidth: 200,
          maxWidth: 500,
          maxHeight: 250,
      });
    });

    <div class="test-container">
      <div class="test-item">Ordered On: 11/19/2014
        <div><input name="qty_0" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_0" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_0" value="788" id="ck_0" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_0">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="test-item">Ordered On: 10/27/2014   
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>   
      </div>   

      <div class="test-item">Ordered On: 11/27/2014   
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>   
      </div>     

      <div class="test-item">Ordered On: 08/27/2015   
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>
        <div><input name="qty_1" value="1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="attr_1" type="hidden">&nbsp;
        <input name="pid_1" value="788" id="ck_1" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="ck_1">aaa_Credit Card</label>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial setting on flex items is `flex-shrink: 1`. This means that flex items will shrink to avoid overflowing the container. That's why your lines of text of wrapping. To see what I'm talking about, add `flex-shrink: 0` to your `.test-item` elements. [*revised demo 1*](https://jsfiddle.net/thuzm1ny/3/)

What you may be looking for is to have the space in the container distributed evenly across items. Consider also releasing the width limitation on the container. [*revised demo 2*](https://jsfiddle.net/thuzm1ny/4/), [*revised demo 3*](https://jsfiddle.net/thuzm1ny/5/)

Comment: Thank you. That made a big difference. I made the change as you mentioned and then realized that in actual use the lines would not be the same width. I changed it to https://jsfiddle.net/thuzm1ny/6/. Is there a way to align those boxes or will that involve defining a width? Leaving them as they are is fine but if I could make it look more orderly it would give a better impression, I  think.

Comment: That's how flexbox works. Unless you define a width, the items will be sized based on their content. You could switch to CSS Grid Layout to solve your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/thuzm1ny/7/

Comment: That's what I assumed but wanted to be sure. I will play around with both of your examples. I appreciate you posting them.